# Integral of an exponential of rational function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, rational-functions

I have an integral of the form $\int_{a}^{b} \text{exp}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\rho^2 m + \sigma^2_u}\right) \frac{1}{m^2}\text{exp}\left(-\frac{\lambda}{m}\right) dm$. Can this integral be found analytically?

Comment: What is the integration variable?

Comment: It was dm, edited.